# Renderscript Non-Invokable functions

Tags: android, c, image, image-processing, renderscript

I am writing a render script code and I need some utility functions.But when I write those functions and compile I get an error saying that invokable functions must return void. They are enforcing this so that all render script invokable functions can run asynchronously. But is there a way to make the functions non invokable? I want to write functions just for use within my render script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them static, that will prevent them from being invokable by the rs compiler.